# eCharts -- Simple stacked line chart not showing data

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am new to eCharts and I am trying to get a stacked line chart to work. The tooltip shows the data correctly, but there is no y-axis scale and no lines or area fills. If I remove the "stack: 'a'" options from the 'series' section, a non-stacked version of the chart renders correctly. My options and data are as follows:

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
        
var option = {
  "animation": false,
  "legend": {
    "show": true,
    "top": "middle",
    "left": "right",
    "orient": "vertical"
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "Total Raised by Type, Month and Year",
    "left": "center"
  },
  "tooltip": {
    "trigger": "axis",
    "axisPointer": {
      "type": "cross",
      "label": {
        "backgroundColor": "#6a7985"
      }
    }
  },
  "dataset": {
    "source": [
      [
        null,
        "Gifts",
        "In Kind",
        "Pledges"
      ],
      [
        "Jul 2017",
        "2508",
        "1",
        "2594"
      ],
      [
        "Aug 2017",
        "3512",
        "2",
        "3631"
      ],
      [
        "Sep 2017",
        "7625",
        "4",
        "7885"
      ],
      [
        "Oct 2017",
        "8026",
        "4",
        "8300"
      ],
      [
        "Nov 2017",
        "9431",
        "5",
        "9753"
      ],
      [
        "Dec 2017",
        "15050",
        "8",
        "15563"
      ],
      [
        "Jan 2018",
        "9030",
        "5",
        "9338"
      ],
      [
        "Feb 2018",
        "7525",
        "4",
        "7781"
      ],
      [
        "Mar 2018",
        "6020",
        "3",
        "6225"
      ],
      [
        "Apr 2018",
        "8528",
        "4",
        "8819"
      ],
      [
        "May 2018",
        "13043",
        "7",
        "13488"
      ],
      [
        "Jun 2018",
        "10033",
        "5",
        "10375"
      ],
      [
        "Jul 2018",
        "4311",
        "4",
        "2159"
      ],
      [
        "Aug 2018",
        "6036",
        "5",
        "3022"
      ],
      [
        "Sep 2018",
        "13106",
        "11",
        "6563"
      ],
      [
        "Oct 2018",
        "13796",
        "12",
        "6908"
      ],
      [
        "Nov 2018",
        "16210",
        "14",
        "8117"
      ],
      [
        "Dec 2018",
        "25867",
        "23",
        "12953"
      ],
      [
        "Jan 2019",
        "15520",
        "14",
        "7772"
      ],
      [
        "Feb 2019",
        "12934",
        "11",
        "6477"
      ],
      [
        "Mar 2019",
        "10347",
        "9",
        "5181"
      ],
      [
        "Apr 2019",
        "14658",
        "13",
        "7340"
      ],
      [
        "May 2019",
        "22418",
        "20",
        "11226"
      ],
      [
        "Jun 2019",
        "17245",
        "15",
        "8636"
      ],
      [
        "Jul 2019",
        "1847",
        "2",
        "1696"
      ],
      [
        "Aug 2019",
        "2586",
        "3",
        "2374"
      ],
      [
        "Sep 2019",
        "5616",
        "6",
        "5155"
      ],
      [
        "Oct 2019",
        "5911",
        "6",
        "5426"
      ],
      [
        "Nov 2019",
        "6946",
        "7",
        "6375"
      ],
      [
        "Dec 2019",
        "11084",
        "11",
        "10173"
      ],
      [
        "Jan 2020",
        "6650",
        "7",
        "6104"
      ],
      [
        "Feb 2020",
        "5542",
        "6",
        "5087"
      ],
      [
        "Mar 2020",
        "4433",
        "5",
        "4069"
      ],
      [
        "Apr 2020",
        "6281",
        "6",
        "5765"
      ],
      [
        "May 2020",
        "9606",
        "10",
        "8817"
      ],
      [
        "Jun 2020",
        "7389",
        "8",
        "6782"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "category",
    "axisLabel": {
      "rotate": 90
    }
  },
  "yAxis": [
    {
      "type": "value",
      "axisLabel": {
        "formatter": "${value}"
      }
    }
  ],
  "series": [
    {
      "type": "line",
      "areaStyle": {},
      "stack": "a"
    },
    {
      "type": "line",
      "areaStyle": {},
      "stack": "a"
    },
    {
      "type": "line",
      "areaStyle": {},
      "stack": "a"
    }
  ]
};

myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/echarts/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```

I've been able to get every other chart type I need to work as expected except this one. What am I missing?

Comment: It appears that if I add the data into the series.data instead of using the dataset.source, it will render. This requires an extra transform of the input data that isn't needed in an unstacked line chart. Would still like to know if this is possible without the extra transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `null` as name for your first dimension but some arbitrary string like 'date':

```
"source": [
      [
        "date",
        "Gifts",
        "In Kind",
        "Pledges"
      ], [...]
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks! I knew it would be something simple.